# Shared Folder as Ignite Store Folder

Tags: ignite

I want to use network shared folder as persistent store path in DataStorageConfiguration.Ignite stucks there.

Can anyone please tell me how to do in ignite?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t recommend putting Ignite’s persistent files on a network volume. The performance and locking characteristics often lead to problems. Fast, local disks are very much preferable.

But to directly answer your question, as [per the documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store):

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="storagePath" value="/opt/storage"/>
        <property name="walPath" value="/opt/wal"/>
        <property name="walArchivePath" value="/opt/walarch"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```